# How to change website limits in IIS with powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, configuration

I need to change the website maxurlsegments, which is a parameter in advanced settings -> limits -> maximum url segments, with powershell to continue automating the deployment of webservers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Example for set the value to 33 for the Default Web Site:

```
import-module WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name limits.maxUrlSegments -Value 33
```